# java jersey retry request on SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, jersey, request, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a Jersey client and want to implement retry upon `SocketTimeoutException`, which is the error I see on the server log. The code skeleton is below. `webtarget` is a `javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget` instance with the url path and queryparams already defined. The issue I'm facing is that `webtarget.request.get()` never throws any SocketTimeoutException so I can't actually catch this exception. Any thoughts how I can actually implement the retry?

```
int i = 0;
Response response;
while (true) {
    try {
        response = webtarget.request().get();
        break;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
        if (i < retryNumber) {
            i++;
        } else {
            // throws some exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont you want to increase the client timeout for a request to avoid the socket timeout exception in first place itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the solution. It turns out the `SocketTimeoutException` is mapped into a `ProcessingException` that is actually thrown by the Jersey client. So the following code worked

```
int i = 0;
Response response;
while (true) {
    try {
        response = webtarget.request().get();
        break;
    } catch (ProcessingException e){
        if (e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException && i < retryNumber) {
            i++;
        } else {
            // throws some exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. The server throws `SocketTimeoutException`, and catches it, and logs it, and returns some HTTP error code to the client. It can't throw an exception to the client.

You need to observe what HTTP error code is returned, and retry on that condition.

Comment: why do you assume that the exception can be thrown only on the server?